# jquery datatables issue for static data

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables-1.10

I have a jquery code where after success i load the datatables

```
$(document).on('click',"#listgroups",function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'action.cfm',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {},
        dataType:'text',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.waitpage').show();
        },
        success : function(data) {  
            $('.waitpage').hide();            
            $('#resultsgroups').html(data).addClass('red');
            addTables();
        },
        error : function(request,error) {
            $('.waitpage').hide();
            alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
        }
    });
});
```

my datatables code is this

```
function addTables() {
    $('#resultswindow').DataTable({ retrieve: true });
}
```

as i am using bootstrap tabs and each tab has server side data happening with ajax calls and then those ajax calls are complete, i tried to reload the results in datatables but the problem is, it works for few tabs and then for some tabs, it just displays a simple table instead of datatables,

anyone can point what i am doing wrong.

There is no server side ajax involved in datatables

Comment: You should include bootstrap as one of your tags. I would add it, but I don't know which version you are using.

Comment: I am using datatables 1.10 and bootstrap 3